# Javascript unsorted list of a questionaire for n number of options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to create a questionnaire for a website, in which I have a set number of questions and a set number of answers. But I now need to change the number of answers to different values(instead of 4, to 2,3,5 etc). I am quite new to web development whatsoever.

In the beginning, I had an unsorted list:

```
question.innerHTML = `<h2>Q${count + 1}. ${questions[count].question}</h2>
<ul class="option_group">
<li class="option">${first}</li>
<li class="option">${second}</li>
<li class="option">${third}</li>
<li class="option">${fourth}</li>
</ul>`;
```

and before that I used the:

```
let[first, second, third, fourth] = questions[count].options;
```

to show the options. I thought of using an array to count each element of the options provided and then change for each question but I just cant seem to find the correct way to form the commands.
Thanks in advance for any recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

```
let html = `<h2>Q${count + 1}. ${questions[count].question}</h2>
<ul class="option_group">`
for (let item of questions[count].question) {
  html += `<li class="option">${item}</li>`
}
html += '</ul>'
```

Comment: i can see the logic behind your answer! it didnt solve the problem but i can try to figure it out. Thanks a lot!